# Android Webview contentHeight has value from last visited page

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

When I invoke Webview.contentHeight, I get every time the value from the last visited site. What have I to do, to get the contentHeight of the new loaded site?

I try this:

```
val view = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.view)
url = edit.text.toString()
url = URLUtil.guessUrl(url)
edit.text = url

if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
  view.loadUrl(url)
  //here I've tried and give the Webview with sleep(30000) some time, but this also don't working
  var cheight = view.contentHeight
  var vHeight = view.height
  var mheight = view.measuredHeight
  var minheight = view.minimumHeight
  Toast.makeText(this, cheight.toString() + " " + vHeight.toString() + " " + mheight.toString() + " " + minheight.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to work around the Problem. To test the behavior afterwards, I get the ContentHeight in a Button.Listener and display the value with Toast.makeText(). Now I get the current value.